# how to use curly braces inside text in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i need to write a text: "{Notes you add appear here}", by the way, the braces have different style thats why the spans.
is there a way to write the braces without "React" recognizing it as a different scope? I havent been able to find anyone addressing this.
Thanks for your time!

```
<div className="trash">
  <p>
    <span>{</span>
      Notes you add appear here
    <span>}</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And old friend helped me:

```
<div className="trash">
 <p>
   <span>{"{"}</span>
     Notes you add appear here
   <span>{"}"}</span>
 </p>
</div>
```